# Y-labels on secondary axis on top of each other

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the following and I notice that the labels on the y-axis is all on top of each other.

[image]

How can I avoid this?

I am using the code below to make the plots:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(18, 7))
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 7))
for i in range(0, len(df_data), 1):
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    _df_data = df_data[i][(df_data[i].wav_um > 9.29) & (df_data[i].wav_um < 9.51)].reset_index(drop=True)
    ax1.plot(_df_data.wav_um, _df_data.mircat_auc, 'o--', linewidth=1, c = 'blue', mfc= 'lightblue', mec='black', ms=4, alpha=0.7, label=hdf5_file_locations[i])
    ax2.plot(_df_data.wav_um, _df_data.thorlabs_pw_mw, 'o--', linewidth=1, c = 'orange', mfc= 'salmon', mec='gray', ms=3, alpha=0.7)

ax1.set_xlabel(r'Wavelength [$\mu m$]', fontsize = 14)
ax1.set_ylabel(r' AUC', fontsize = 14, color='blue')
ax2.set_ylabel(r' power [mW]', fontsize = 14, color='orange')
ax1.tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=15)
ax2.grid(which='both', color='0.9', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot run the code, as the `df_data` object is not defined. However just from looking at the code, I can tell you should move the axis cloning `ax2 = ax1.twinx()` out of the loop. Right now you create a new twin axis on every iteration, while you actually only need one. So try the following instead:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(18, 7))
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 7))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

for i in range(0, len(df_data), 1):
    _df_data = df_data[i][(df_data[i].wav_um > 9.29) & (df_data[i].wav_um < 9.51)].reset_index(drop=True)
    ax1.plot(_df_data.wav_um, _df_data.mircat_auc, 'o--', linewidth=1, c = 'blue', mfc= 'lightblue', mec='black', ms=4, alpha=0.7, label=hdf5_file_locations[i])
    ax2.plot(_df_data.wav_um, _df_data.thorlabs_pw_mw, 'o--', linewidth=1, c = 'orange', mfc= 'salmon', mec='gray', ms=3, alpha=0.7)

ax1.set_xlabel(r'Wavelength [$\mu m$]', fontsize = 14)
ax1.set_ylabel(r' AUC', fontsize = 14, color='blue')
ax2.set_ylabel(r' power [mW]', fontsize = 14, color='orange')
ax1.tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=15)
ax2.grid(which='both', color='0.9', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
```

I hope this helps!